# Ruby get arrays of dates based on given period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have question is there maybe a fine simple solution to this task:

I have `first_date = "2011-02-02"` , `last_date = "2013-01-20"` and `period = 90 (days)`.

I need to get arrays with two elements for example:
`[first_date, first_date + period] ... [some_date, last_date]`.

I will make it with some kind of a loop but maybe there is some nice fancy way to do this :D.

Answer (score 1):

Date has a step method:

```
require 'date'
first_date = Date.parse("2011-02-02")
last_date = Date.parse("2013-02-20")
period = 90

p first_date.step(last_date-period, period).map{|d| [d, d+period]}
#or
p first_date.step(last_date, period).map.each_cons(2).to_a
```

Comment: Mmm, I didn't know about the `step` method (1.9.3 only). It would have been perfect if its semantics was to fully respect the limit argument. This also requires a last step to ensure the last range ends correctly on `last_date`, as requested. Very helpful nevertheless!

Comment: @KamilŁęczycki If you like this answer (even though mine came earlier and is more correct :-P), you should click the checkmark next to it. Additionally you can click on the up arrow next to all the answers you consider helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'pp'
require 'date'

first_date=Date.parse "2011-02-02"
last_date=Date.parse "2013-01-20"
period = 90
periods = []

current = first_date
last = current + period

while(last < last_date ) do
  periods << [current, last]
  current = last  
  last = current + period
end

if periods[-1][1] != last_date  
  periods << [periods[-1][1], last_date]
end

p periods
```

I am assuming that the last period must end on `last_date` regardless of its length, as your question implies.

Comment: Since you're in a RoR context you may find nice and fancy to use the [calculations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/DateTime/Calculations.html) module